# Add Dynamic LineColor To Biograph Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hey i am trying to paint the edges of a biograph, i want to paint each time a new edge and keep the previews painted edges.

Here is my code

```
A = sparse(6,6);
A(Router1,Router2)=bool;
ids = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
grp = view(biograph(A,ids));
if bool == 0
  [dist,path,pred1] = graphshortestpath(A,Router1,Router2);
  edges = getedgesbynodeid(grp,get(grp.Nodes(path),'ID'));
  set(edges,'LineColor',[1 0 0])
  set(edges,'LineWidth',1.5)
 end
```

[image]

Ass you can see i get the wanted edge painted in red.

[image]

now i am tring to paint another edge but i cant find a way to save the already painted one.
i want thinking about saving the path but i couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: can you make `edges` an array? `edges{end+1} = getedgesbynodeid(grp,get(grp.Nodes(path),'ID'))`

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'edges'.

Error in switchnetwork (line 138)
                                edges{end+1} = getedgesbynodeid(grp,get(grp.Nodes(path),'ID'));
 cant make it work like this..